# improve performance of list creation

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

How can I improve significantly the speed of the following code?

```
nmax = 10000000;
r = Range[nmax];
res = ({#, #^2, If[Mod[#, 2] == 0, "even", "odd"]} & /@ r); // AbsoluteTiming

{15.3145, Null}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
res = Transpose[{r, r^2, Mod[r, 2]}];
```

This is about 50 times faster than the original code on my machine and contains the same information. I replaced the strings by integers (`0` or `1`), because that allows one to use vectorization and [packed arrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3496).

If you insist on the strings, you can try

```
res = Transpose[{r, r^2, {"odd", "even"}[[Mod[r, 2, 1]]]}];
```

which is still 5 times faster than the original code.
But this also shows drastically that transposing an unpackedable array can be very expensive. (Run the code without `Transpose` and compare the runtime.)

Comment: Thank you. Your solution with the strings is on my computer about four times faster than my code.

Answer (score 3):

Another trick, not so efficient.

```
nmax = 1000;
r = Range[nmax];
f[x_] := {x, x^2, If[EvenQ@x, "even", "odd"]};
SetAttributes[f, Listable];
res1 = (f@r); // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.0026543, Null}

This is the origin code.

> {0.003949, Null}

```
res1 == res2
```

> True